# How to set GSSAPIAuthentication and GSSAPIDelegateCredentials attributes through CPAN module Net-OpenSSH

Tags: perl, ssh, cpan, openssh

I am trying to create a ssh handle through module http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.62/. I tried setting `GSSAPIAuthentication` and `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials` to "No", but these setting don't take effect if my `.ssh/config` is like this:

```
$ cat myusername/.ssh/config 

Host *
    CheckHostIP no
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    HashKnownHosts no
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    LogLevel ERROR
```

This is how I try to set `GSSAPIAuthentication` and `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials`. Also is there a way to give `-F` option in open ssh constructor so that by default ssh uses some other config file rather than using the one user my user name?

```
$self->{ssh} = Net::OpenSSH->new($host,
user => $username,
passwd => $password,
timeout => $timeout,
default_stderr_discard => 1,
kill_ssh_on_timeout => 1,
master_opts => [-o => "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
    -o => "GSSAPIAuthentication=no", 
    -o => "GSSAPIDelegateCredentials=no",
    -o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add -F => 'somepath/config' under master_opts:

master_opts => [-F => 'somepath/config']

and another line like this:

$self->{ssh}->{_ssh_opts} = ['-F', 'somepath/config'];'